# jquery map and array of arrays with dynatree

Tags: jquery, arrays, dictionary, dynatree

Im trying to create an array of arrays for a table (using titles from dynaTree, within onSelect function). I can succesfully retrieve the dynatree titles from the nodes, but whatever I do I cant seem to make an array of arrays from these values.

only array of string titles...bascially the return line ignores the array brackets and splice?

```
       onSelect: function(flag, node) 
        {
            var selectedNodes = node.tree.getSelectedNodes();

            var selectedKeys = $.map(selectedNodes, function(node)
            {
                return node.data.id;
            });

            var selectedTitles = $.map(selectedNodes, function(node)
            {        
                var name = node.data.title;
                name = name.substring(0,4);

                if(name == 'Room')
                {
                    var floor = node.getParent();
                    var building = floor.getParent();

                    //PROBLEM CODE(not creating arrays):
                    return([node.data.title,floor.data.title,building.data.title] );                
                }
            });

            console.log("Selected Titles: " + selectedTitles);

        },
```

CURRENT RESULTS:

```
Selected Titles: Room 115,Floor 1,Chemistry, Room 116,Floor 01,Chemistry,
Room 114,Floor 01,Chemistry, Room 113,Floor 01,Chemistry, Room 112,Floor 
01,Chemistry, Room 110,Floor 01,Chemistry, Room 109,Floor 01,Chemistry, Room 
109A,Floor 01,Chemistry
```

DESIRED RESULTS:

```
Selected Titles: [Room 115,Floor 1,Chemistry],[Room 116,Floor 01,Chemistry],
[Room 114,Floor 01,Chemistry],[Room 113,Floor 01,Chemistry],[Room 112,Floor  
01,Chemistry],[Room 110,Floor 01,Chemistry],[Room 109,Floor 01,Chemistry],  
[Room 109A,Floor 01,Chemistry]
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle with sample data? and also try to remove `join(", ")`.

Comment: Don't use alert to inspect resultant .. log it to console. Not sure why you need to use `splice()` when you aren't changing original structure

Comment: Surely you want `return [node.data.title, floor.data.title, building.data.title]`?

Comment: **@Roamer-1888** Yeah just tried doing exactly that and get same result with no arrays....trying everything really

Comment: **@Learner** Just tried removing join...thought that was it but still array of strings.

Comment: As charlietfl says, inspect with console.log, not alert .... and don't join

Comment: **@charlietfl** Now using console.log with same results...one giant array of strings.

Comment: your problem is in your console.log.  You're doing an implicit string conversion because you're adding 'Selected Tiles: ' to your output.  You need to just log out your tiles.  If you actually need to build a string similar to your desired results, that would require a simple string builder.

Comment: **@John Green** Thanks for advice..console did output slightly differently, but still same problem (all string no sub-arrays)..CONSOLE: `Array [ "Room 115", "Floor 1", "Chemistry", "Room 116", "Floor 01", "Chemistry", "Room 114", "Floor 01", "Chemistry", "Room 113", 38 more… ]`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!! I done everything in the previous comments and didnt see any change...then tried adding another array container arround the return statement.

Thanks to **charlietfl** & **John Green** for recomending the console log and removing the string, without altering this sloppy code, the structure would not be visable as an array of arrays.

```
return( [[node.data.title,floor.data.title,building.data.title]]);
```

I dont know why the map method requies a containing array?... but works as intended!